# Warning of System.OutOfMemoryException while building an App

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm new to Xamarin. While Building my project, I came across this Warning. I tried to look for its solutions, but none of them resolved this issue.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Source  Suppression State
Warning     Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
at Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.MsfDirectory..ctor(PdbReader reader, PdbFileHeader head, BitAccess bits)
at Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.PdbFile.LoadFunctions(Stream read, BitAccess bits, Boolean readAllStrings)
at Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.PdbFile.LoadFunctions(Stream read, Boolean readAllStrings)
at Pdb2Mdb.Converter.Convert(String filename)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ConvertDebuggingFiles.Execute()
```

Comment: Have you checked this: [OutOfMemoryException when building Droid project](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/13534/outofmemoryexception-when-building-droid-project.html).

Answer (score -1):

Thats is related to RAM being not enough .

You can try increasing virtual memory .

If you are working on MAC - you need 8 gb ram that should do .

on Windows when we were getting that problem we had to increase that to 16 gb to get rid of it .( vs and android studio both were there though) .

Comment: how to increase virtual memory for windows? @saket

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?dcr=0&source=hp&q=how+to+increase+virtual+memory+in+windows+10&oq=how+to+increase+virtual+memory+in+windows+10&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l3j0i22i30k1l4.1220.1220.0.1396.1.1.0.0.0.0.30.30.1.1.0....0...1.2.64.psy-ab..0.1.30....0.Y562rKdVIVQ